# Replacing multiple character instances from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

So I have this piece of code:

```
var thisValue = $("input[id*=ID222]").val(); 
thisValue = thisValue.replace(',','');
```

Basically I want to remove all commas in this input element for taking it up for further processing. The above code works when there is only one comma in the field, but doesn't work for multiple commas. Is there another way? I tried replaceAll, and it didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace multiple instances of a character in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320056/replace-multiple-instances-of-a-character-in-a-string)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove "," from a string in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908608/how-to-remove-from-a-string-in-javascript). This is really the exact same question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do a global replace using a regular expression. You can't do this by passing a string to `replace`:

```
thisValue = thisValue.replace(/,/g,'');
```